# Highmaps: How to emphasize mapline

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am building a "flight path" map based on this template: https://jsfiddle.net/5hc24qa9/

There are three elements that I am struggling to implement (as requested by our designer):

1. How can I highlight or otherwise emphasize an individual flight path (e.g. London-Leeds) when hovering.  I've tried

```
series = [{
  ...
  type: 'mapline',
  states: {
      hover: {
         brightness: 0.8
      }
  },
  ...
}]
```

Unfortunately, it does not change the appearance of the data line when I hover over it.

More generally, is there a way to interact with the line segment to customize appearance?  If I wanted to apply an arc-gradient for color, for example, or vary the width of the line between London and Leeds (but not between London and Glasgow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `series.mapline.events.point.mouseOver` and `mouseOut` callbacks and update the hovered point by using the `point.update` feature.

Demo (test on the orange path): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/o6g1q3x4/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.mapline.point.events

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#update

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  On my map, I set the line width to change on mouseOver, and to return to normal when on mouseOut. (Demo, on orange path: https://jsfiddle.net/q4detjrL/).  When I zoom in, though, the line width is the larger size until mouseover, then the line jumps, and assumes proper size.  Any idea on how to fix that? A bug I should report?

Comment: @BrianWitte it seems that it is a bug, I reported it on the Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/14412

Comment: @BrianWitte Notice that the `workaround` showed up in the comment.